# Show $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i) = \bigcup f^{-1}(B_i)$ proof done correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i) = \bigcup f^{-1}(B_i)$

Attmept: I used induction:

We know it is true for $i = 1$ where $i\in \mathbb N$
Confirm for $i = 2$:
$f^{-1}(B_1\cup B_2) = f^{-1}(B_1) \cup f^{-1}(B_2)$

Assume true for $i = k$, where $k \ge 2$:
$$\implies f^{-1}(\bigcup B_k) = \bigcup f^{-1}(B_k)$$

Now for $i = k+1$:

$$f^{-1}(\bigcup B_{k+1}) = f^{-1}(\bigcup B_k \cup B_{k+1})$$ 
by the first induction step of $i = 2$:

$$\implies f^{-1}(\bigcup B_k) \cup f^{-1}(B_{k+1}) = \bigcup f^{-1}(B_{k+1})$$

done. or QED because I'm feeling good about this.

Done correct?

Comment: How would I write scripts underneath and above my $\bigcup$ ?

Comment: No proof can be right without an explanation of the notation used.  What is $B$?  What is $B_i$?  What os $f$?

Comment: You don't need induction here, I would show $L \subset R$ and $R \subset L$ to prove $L=R$.

Comment: Are you sure that the set: $\{B_i\,;B_i\in B\}$ is finite or countable to use induction?

Comment: how would I show via the containment approach? spcifically how to treat the infinte size of the sets? WOuld it just be the same procedure as if I was just doing two sets such as $A\cup B$ ?

Comment: $B$ is supposed to be "script B" to describe the collection of sets. Then $B_i$ would be the individual sets. Actually @hamid I don't know, the text asked for the arbitrary union and I remember reading that when it comes to infinites unions there are some subtle complications so I assumed countable sets.

Comment: @dc3rd: You should show:  
$f^{-1}(\bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i) \subseteq \bigcup f^{-1}(B_i)$  
And:  
$\bigcup f^{-1}(B_i)\subseteq f^{-1}(\bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i)$

Comment: @hamidkamali yes I have proved it for the simple case, now I want to do it for the general one.

Comment: @dc3rd: I have shown the containment approach below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment:

Suppose: $$x\in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i)$$ Then: $$f(x)\in \bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i$$ So there is some $A \in B$ such that $f(x) \in A$, hence $x \in f^{-1}(A) \subset \bigcup_{B_i\in B} f^{-1}(B_i)$.
Now suppose: $$x\in \bigcup_{B_i\in B} f^{-1}(B_i)$$ Then, there is some $A \in B$ such that $$x \in f^{-1}(A)$$ And since $$A \subset \bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i$$ We
have: $$f^{-1}(A) \subset f^{-1}(\bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i) $$ Hence:
$$x \in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{B_i\in B}B_i) $$ As an aside, the horrendous notation $B_i\in B$ is almost certain to cause confusion.

Comment: Is there no "script B" command to differentiate the two B's that I have? because that was essentially what I was trying to do, where "script B" represented the collection of sets

Comment: Well, I would write ${\cal B}$ for the collection of index sets, and then, at worst, something like $B \in {\cal B}$ (this is still fraught with potential for ambiguity, especially if age has taken its toll on your eyes :-)).

Comment: ah. that was the tex command I was looking for. Thanks. I'll keep in mind a clearer differentiation of sets.